# Rotation of ViewController in TabbarController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I have a custom UIViewController in a UITabbarController and want to respond to rotation events. When a rotation occurs, the tabbarcontroller and the viewcontroller get rotated. However, the view in the viewcontroller doesn't get redrawn properly: the layout doesn't autoresize and it is black on parts of the screen.

The strange thing is that it works when I go to another tab and the back again to my original viewcontroller.

What could possibly be wrong? I checked that `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation` is being called. However, the `view.frame.size` values are still the old ones from before the rotation. That's probably not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```